# Why are my particles speeding up when I press button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm making a confetti launcher that creates squares  and places them at the top of the screen, they each have a certain gravity and direction to the side. I have a button that makes 100 of them at a time. Every time I press the button, however, it creates new ones, but also it speeds up the movement of the existing squares.

```js
var width1 = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
  document.body.clientWidth;
var height1 = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
  document.body.clientHeight;
let canvas = document.getElementById('confetti');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = width1;
canvas.height = height1;
let pieces = [];
let numberOfPieces = 100;
let lastUpdateTime = Date.now();
var a = 0;
var intervalID;

function randomColor() {
  let colors = ['#999999ff', '#b7b7b7ff', ' #D3D3D3', '#ffff00 ', '#d9d9d9ff'];
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

function update() {
  let now = Date.now(),
    dt = now - lastUpdateTime;

  for (let i = pieces.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let p = pieces[i];

    if (p.y > canvas.height) {
      pieces.splice(i, 1);
      continue;
    }

    p.y += p.gravity * dt;
    p.rotation += p.rotationSpeed * dt;
    p.x += p.direction;
  }


  if (pieces.length < numberOfPieces) {
    for (var b = pieces.length; b < numberOfPieces; b++) {
      pieces.push(new Piece(Math.random() * canvas.width, -20));
      b--;
      numberOfPieces--;
    }
  }
  lastUpdateTime = now;
  a++;
  if (a >= 1) {
    numberOfPieces = 0;
    //console.log("number of pieces: " + numberOfPieces + " pieces.length: " + pieces.length);
  }
}

function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  pieces.forEach(function(p) {
    ctx.save();

    ctx.fillStyle = p.color;

    ctx.translate(p.x + p.size / 2, p.y + p.size / 2);
    ctx.rotate(p.rotation);

    ctx.fillRect(-p.size / 2, -p.size / 2, p.size, p.size);

    ctx.restore();
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function Piece(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = (Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.75) * 15;
  this.gravity = (Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.75) * 0.15;
  var c = Math.random()
  if (c > 0.5) {
    this.direction = -(Math.random() * 0.6);
  } else {
    this.direction = (Math.random() * 0.6);
  }
  this.rotation = (Math.PI * 2) * Math.random();
  this.rotationSpeed = (Math.PI * 2) * (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.0005;
  this.color = randomColor();
}

while (pieces.length < numberOfPieces) {
  pieces.push(new Piece(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height));
}
var bye = 0;

function myfunction() {
  var hello = Date.now();

  var difference = hello - bye;
  if (difference > 1000) {
    a = 0;
    numberOfPieces = pieces.length + 100;

    intervalID = setInterval(update, 30);
    draw();
    bye = Date.now();
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas id="confetti"></canvas>
<button style="float: right; border: 1px blue solid; width: 100px; height: 100px;" onclick="myfunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Yes, they are, in the lateral direction. Initially they almost like fall straight. After 1000 clicks the lateral movement increases.

Comment: Each of your button clicks is starting a new animation with its own interval, not stopping the previous one. After clicking twice, you have two animation intervals running concurrently, which do twice the number of updates in the same time.

Comment: Also, why do you have separate update and draw loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixes by order of importance:

- Run your ***engine*** only once! (not on every click. PS: you were not clearing your interval)
- **Remove `setInterval`**, you already use `requestAnimationFrame()` as *engine*
- **Performance** wise, **create a `pieces = {}` Object** (instead of Array), and on creation store inside your pieces by `this.id` (just a random number)
- Remove the `draw()` method. Instead **create a `this.draw()` method** for every 
  *confetto*.
- Put your **removal** logic inside the `this.draw()` method. To remove the piece from our `pieces` Object - simply use `delete pieces[this.id]`
- Add the logic to also remove a piece from the `pieces` Object - if it goes out of the **left/right canvas edges**
- Inside your engine simply loop the `pieces` and call each piece's `.draw()` method.
- No need to pass arguments to the `Piece` constructor. Keep it simple and just use `new Piece();`
- Create a reusable `rnd(min, max)` function to return a float from `min` to `max` (excluded)
- Remove unnecessary variables (like `a` or `lastUpdateTime`)
- Remove unnecessary `while` out-of-function init loops.
- Rename `myfunction()` to something meaningful, i.e: `createConfetti()`
- Put `colors` Array in *"root"* scope. Those are your static values.
- Use `Element.addEventListener()` instead of inline JavaScript like `onclick`.
- Know he difference between `const` and `let` and use accordingly. You don't need `var` any more.

Here's the example:

```js
const width1 = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
  document.body.clientWidth;
const height1 = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
  document.body.clientHeight;
const canvas = document.getElementById('confetti');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const pieces = {}; // For better delete performance
const numberOfPieces = 100;
const colors = ['#999999', '#b7b7b7', '#D3D3D3', '#f48024', '#d9d9d9'];
const rnd = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

let bye = 0;

canvas.width = width1;
canvas.height = height1;

function Piece() {
  this.id = rnd(0, 1e3);
  this.g = rnd(0.7, 2);
  this.w = rnd(5, 25);
  this.x = rnd(0, canvas.width);
  this.y = -this.w;
  this.dir = rnd(0, 1) > 0.5 ? rnd(0, 0.5) : -rnd(0, 0.5);
  this.r = rnd(1, 8);
  this.rSpeed = rnd(1, 5) * 0.01;
  this.color = colors[~~rnd(0, colors.length)];
  this.draw = () => {
    if (this.y > canvas.height || this.x < -this.w || this.x > canvas.width + this.w) {
      delete pieces[this.id];
      return;
    }
    this.y += this.g;
    this.r += this.rSpeed;
    this.x += this.dir;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.translate(this.x + this.w / 2, this.y + this.w / 2);
    ctx.rotate(this.r);
    ctx.fillRect(-this.w / 2, -this.w / 2, this.w, this.w);
    ctx.restore();
  }
  // populate into object
  pieces[this.id] = this;
}

function createConfetti() {
  const hi = Date.now();
  if (hi - bye <= 1000) return;
  bye = hi;
  // Populate pieces array
  let i = numberOfPieces;
  while (i) {
    new Piece();
    i--;
  }
}

function engine() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const piecesIDs = Object.keys(pieces);
  if (piecesIDs.length) {
    piecesIDs.forEach(id => pieces[id].draw());
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}

engine(); // Start engine once! Not on every click
document.querySelector('#createConfetti').addEventListener('click', createConfetti);
```

```css
* { margin:0; }
button { z-index:1; position:absolute; }
#confetti { display:block; }
```

```html
<button id="createConfetti">Click me</button>
<canvas id="confetti"></canvas>
```